# Using like statement with %

Tags: html, mysql

I have a select box, in which the option value works as a variable for the query.

```
<option value="1">Monday</option>
```

The part of the query we're interested in is this:

```
AND phpvms_schedules.daysofweek LIKE '%{$day}%'";
```

`LIKE '%{$day}%'` is a variable taken from option value. Basically, it specifies a given day and checks for `option value` presence in `daysofweek` column in `db_schedules` table.
However, I'd like to add more numbers to the option value, to basically search ALL schedules in the table.

```
<option value="1234560">All Days</option>
```

If I do this, I simply get no results.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this before the query:

```
if ($day == 1234560)
    $day = '';
```

This would give `WHERE LIKE '%%'` and would return all weekdays.

Comment: Thank you, works nicely, however the intended output of 'All Days` option is to output ALL schedules, while it does only those which are of exact value `1234560`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your database design could be improved by a lot. Consider using JOIN along with an extra database connected to the schema which only contains one of the weeks. then you can have 7 rows for cases with full weeks, and you don't have to use LIKE at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the value like '1','2','3' then make the query

```
AND phpvms_schedules.daysofweek In (%{$day}%)
```

Comment: You don't use `%` with `IN`.